# How to find a list of unique shortest paths in a list of paths?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, shortest-path

Imagine I have a tree graph as shown below, where a node can have multiple children, and so on.. (a node can have only 1 parent). If I have a list of paths along that graph, how can I find a subset of those paths that are unique and shortest?

[image]

Example Input (List of paths):

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 7]
[1, 8, 9, 10]
```

Expected Output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 7]
[1, 8, 9, 10]
```

The `[1, 2, 3]` path is ignored because it is longer than `[1, 2]`, while the `[1, 8, 9, 10]` path is kept because it is unique.

Comment: What is the expected output for `[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 4]` ?

Comment: @Cid if [1] or [1,2] don't exist, both should appear in the output since they are unique.

Comment: So basically if a prefix exists, then you remove that element?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it looks like. The problem become really simpler, the terms *graph* and *tree* can be ignored since the whole "roads" are send as input. There is no need to parse the tree, this is just array processing. *shortest path* is here, in my opinion, badly used

Comment: @Cid: well we can make a prefix-tree here we update for each item,but indeed, it is simpler in terms of *graph* and *tree*.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology was misleading?

Comment: Are nodes' label unique? i.e., can we have two nodes with the same `1` label?

Comment: Nodes labels are unique

Answer (score 2):

First, sort the input paths by length. Maintain a set of leaf nodes. This will contain the last node of each valid path. After adding a leaf node, we'll forbid any path which includes that leaf node. When you add a path, check each of its members against the set of leaf nodes. If you get a match then the path is invalid, otherwise it's valid and you should add it's final element to the set of leaf nodes.

This is O(n log n) in the number of lists and linear in the number of elements across all lists.

Comment: Assuming the longest path's length `s` and the number of paths `n`, the complexity would be actually `O(n*log n*s)`.

Comment: @Emadpres Say n is the number of paths and m is the number of elements. Then this is O(n log n) + O(m). I don't see why you think n*s comes into it.

Comment: @Dave i think @Emadpres is right. Try your algorithm for these paths: `[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,6,7],[1,8,9]`

Comment: @nightfury1204 Well, in the case where all the paths are the same length then m = s*n so I agree for this case, but it isn't generally true. Maybe it's unclear what I meant by m? I mean the sum of the lengths of the paths, not the number of unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a tree using these path. For each path, try to traverse from first node of the path to the last node of the path by setting edge to consecutive node.Mark last node of the path as leaf node after traversing each path. If you find any node marked as a leaf when traversing a path, you will stop traversing. Also remove the child of the node that marked as a leaf node. Every path from root node to leaf node in the final tree will be you answer. See figure below for more clarification:
[image]

Complexity will be sum of all path's length.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Also remove the child of the node that marked as a leaf node*"?

Comment: @Emadpres see in the figure. In `After path 3` node `2` has child `3` and `4`. `After path 4` [1,2]  remove child of node 2.